# how to remove an entry from orderedDict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to obtain top 20 entries from a dictionary based on value. I used orderedDict to sort the entries by value. But when i'm trying to delete an entry from the orderedDict(to maintain a constant length of orderedDict i.e. 20) it doesnt happen.

I wrote the following code:

```
while linecount>0:
    line=images.readline().split()
    #compute "score" for each line
    if (len(result)<20):
        result.update({(str(line)):score})
    else:
            if(len(result)==20):
                   result=OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
                   if(result.items()[0][1]<score):
                       del result.items()[0]
                       temp=str(line)
                       result.update({temp:score})
```

But the delete/remove does not happen at the step:

```
 del result.items()[0]
```

and the length of result remains 21 once it gets to that(21) value

what am i doing wrong, how else could i do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are removing an item from the list returned by `.items()`. You need to delete from the dictionary instead:

```
result.popitem(last=False)
```

[`OrderedDict.popitem()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) returns the first or last key-value, after deleting it. Setting `last` to `False` signals you wanted to remove the first.

Note that you can test against *just* the first value:

```
if result.values()[0] < score:
```

I'd also just use key assignment instead of `.update()` for just one element:

```
result[str(line)] = score  # instead of temp=str(line); result.update({temp:score})
```

Comment: btw from python 3.6 (cpython) / 3.7 (all versions), regular `dict`s also maintain order, and `popitem` removes the last added item; to remove the first item use `(k := next(iter(d)), d.pop(k))`. As per docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Comment: @fantabolous you can add pypy versions going further back (don't know the version range), that's where the new dict implementation came from.